# JNA structure memory allocation in array is incorrect

Tags: java, jna, allocation

I have the problem that the memory allocation is incorrect. I think so because the bits are shifted between the attributes.

this is the native code:

```c
typedef struct s_xl_channel_config {
    char                name [32];
    unsigned char       hwType;                               
    unsigned char       hwIndex;                             
    unsigned char       hwChannel;                           
    unsigned short      transceiverType;                     
    unsigned short      transceiverState;                   
    unsigned short      configError;                         
    unsigned char       channelIndex;                       
    unsigned __int64    channelMask;                         
    unsigned int        channelCapabilities;                 
    unsigned int        channelBusCapabilities;                       
    unsigned char       isOnBus;                             
    unsigned int        connectedBusType;                   
    XLbusParams         busParams;
    unsigned int        _doNotUse;                                                                         
    unsigned int        driverVersion;           
    unsigned int        interfaceVersion;                   
    unsigned int        raw_data[10];                   
    unsigned int        serialNumber;
    unsigned int        articleNumber;
    char                transceiverName [32]; 
    unsigned int        specialCabFlags;                     
    unsigned int        dominantTimeout;                     
    unsigned char       dominantRecessiveDelay;             
    unsigned char       recessiveDominantDelay;             
    unsigned char       connectionInfo;                     
    unsigned char       currentlyAvailableTimestamps;         
    unsigned short      minimalSupplyVoltage;                 
    unsigned short      maximalSupplyVoltage;                 
    unsigned int        maximalBaudrate;                     
    unsigned char       fpgaCoreCapabilities;               
    unsigned char       specialDeviceStatus;                 
    unsigned short      channelBusActiveCapabilities;       
    unsigned short      breakOffset;                         
    unsigned short      delimiterOffset;                     
    unsigned int        reserved[3];
} XL_CHANNEL_CONFIG;
```

My java Code is this:

```java
@FieldOrder ({"name", "hwType", "hwIndex", "hwChannel", "transceiverType",
  "transceiverState", "configError", "channelIndex", "channelMask", 
  "channelCapabilities", "channelBusCapabilities", "isOnBus", "connectedBusType", 
  "busParams",    "_doNotUse", "driverVersion", "interfaceVersion", "raw_data", 
  "serialNumber", "articleNumber", "transceiverName", "specialCabFlags", 
  "dominantTimeout", "dominantRecessiveDelay", "recessiveDominantDelay", 
  "connectionInfo", "currentlyAvailableTimestamps", "minimalSupplyVoltage", 
  "maximalSupplyVoltage", "maximalBaudrate", "fpgaCoreCapabilities", 
  "specialDeviceStatus", "channelBusActiveCapabilities", "breakOffset", 
  "delimiterOffset", "reserved"})
public class XLchannelConfig extends Structure{

    public byte[] name = new byte[32];
    public byte hwType;
    public byte hwIndex;
    public byte hwChannel;
    public short transceiverType;
    public short transceiverState;
    public short configError;
    public byte channelIndex;
    public Nativelong channelMask;
    public int channelCapabilities;
    public int channelBusCapabilities;
    public byte isOnBus;
    public int connectedBusType;
    public XLbusParams busParams= new XLbusParams();
    public int _doNotUse;
    public int driverVersion;
    public int interfaceVersion;
    public int[] raw_data = new int[(10)];
    public int serialNumber;
    public int articleNumber;
    public byte[] transceiverName = new byte[32];
    public int specialCabFlags;
    public int dominantTimeout;
    public byte dominantRecessiveDelay;
    public byte recessiveDominantDelay;
    public byte connectionInfo;
    public byte currentlyAvailableTimestamps;
    public short minimalSupplyVoltage;
    public short maximalSupplyVoltage;
    public int maximalBaudrate;
    public byte fpgaCoreCapabilities;
    public byte specialDeviceStatus;
    public short channelBusActiveCapabilities;
    public short breakOffset;
    public short delimiterOffset;
    public int[] reserved = new int[3];
    
    public XLchannelConfig() {
        super();        
    }
```

The XLchannelConfig class is in an array that I initialized with `.toArray()`.
When I output the attributes, I see that the values ​​are shifted. It looks like the bits have shifted from one attribute to the next. I suspect that it is due to the wrong data type, but I cannot determine which it is.

The toString print this out:

```
XLchannelConfig [name=Virtual Channel 1               , hwType=1, hwIndex=0, hwChannel=0, transceiverType=0, transceiverState=0, channelIndex=1, channelMask=0, channelCapabilities=458752, channelBusCapabilities=106496, isOnBus=1, connectedBusType=16777216, driverVersion=67830784, interfaceVersion=0, raw_data=[0, 0, 0, 65536, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], serialNumber=0, articleNumber=536870912, transceiverName=Virtual CAN                    , specialCabFlags=0, dominantTimeout=0, reserved=[0, 0, 1442840576], busParams=XLbusParams [busType=536870912]]

XLchannelConfig [name=irtual Channel 2               , hwType=0, hwIndex=1, hwChannel=22, transceiverType=0, transceiverState=0, channelIndex=0, channelMask=0, channelCapabilities=1792, channelBusCapabilities=16777632, isOnBus=0, connectedBusType=65536, driverVersion=264964, interfaceVersion=0, raw_data=[0, 0, 0, 256, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], serialNumber=0, articleNumber=1444937728, transceiverName=irtual CAN                    , specialCabFlags=0, dominantTimeout=0, reserved=[0, 0, 0], busParams=XLbusParams [busType=-1591738368]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms show an an extra single byte in your mapping.  The last element of the `reserved` field includes the byte `0x56` which corresponds to the letter "V" missing from the second element.  So we need to look for that extra byte.

The header file bus types go only up to `0x100`.  Your output has the bus type as `0x20000000` suggesting the error is occurring before the `XLbusParams` union.  It's definitely occurring before the `transcieverName` which shows an extra non-null byte as the last character. Other than `channelMask` (see below, would be 4-byte offset) the mappings look correct.

One possible mismatch that could explain a single byte could be alignment of the structure fields.  The name takes 32 bytes, and then there are three 1-byte fields followed by three 2-byte fields. This would have one of the `short` fields crossing a 4-byte or 8-byte boundary.  You might consider using different JNA Structure alignments, such as [Structure.ALIGN_NONE](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#ALIGN_NONE):

```java
public XLchannelConfig() {
    super(Structure.ALIGN_NONE);
}
```

Other mapping comments:

The `channelMask` field in the C header is an explicit 64-bit type (`int64`), and thus should be directly mapped to Java's 64-bit `long`.  The only time you should use `NativeLong` as a mapping is when the native type is `long`.  This can be either 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on both operating system and bitness.  This would (possibly) under-allocate by 4 bytes, however, and may not be the problem.

In copies of the header file in the API, I do not see the `_doNotUse` field that you include. Are you sure it should be included? This adds 4 bytes to the mapping.  Are you certain the header file you've copied matches the version of the API binary that you're using?

Another potential source of an issue is the `XLbusParams` type.  The [API](https://devel.hds.utc.fr/software/pacpus/browser/pacpussensors/trunk/CanGateway/driver/vxlapi.h) shows that's a union with an `int` type and 32 bytes of data.  If you have not properly mapped the union (at least the largest member) that could also cause an offset.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel!! you are awesome. I changed it to ALIGN_NONE and changed form NativeLong to long and now it is working perfectly